# Why is Xamarin.* a synonym of mono* and not the other way round?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

While I personally think Monotouch and Monodroid are cooler names, they are both the older names of [Xamarin.iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/monotouch/synonyms) and [Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/monodroid/synonyms), respectively.

Is there any specific reason for the tags to use the old names instead of the new ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, this doesn't really make any sense; there's a good chance this is gonna just end up confusing more people as usage increases for these.

I've reversed the direction of these synonyms and merged existing questions into the current names for these.